internetarchive Python module unable to find collection contents
I am trying to download all files from this collection: "https://archive.org/details/dharmarthtrustjkcollectionbyegangotri?tab=about".
I am using following codes to try out downloading but, it seems to be not working. What I am doing wrong here? I have already done successful pip install of internet archive library.
from internetarchive import download

download('dharmarthtrustjkcollectionbyegangotri', glob_pattern='*.pdf',dry_run = 'TRUE', verbose = 'TRUE', ignore_existing = 'TRUE')

The error I am getting is
"skipping dharmarthtrustjkcollectionbyegangotri, no matching files found."

